# update value in each element of a list in C# of VS2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio, list

I need to update value in each element of a list in C# of VS2013.

The code:

```
var wl = myList.ToArray();
List<myElement> tl = new List<myElement>();
tl = givenList; // I need to update values in element in this list
for(int p =0; p < wl.Count(); ++p)
{
    decimal? fv = (wl[p].value * 10) / ((decimal?)a_constant);
    tl.ToArray()[p].value = fv; // this cannot update the value
}
myList = tl;
```

But, the `tl.ToArray()[p].value = fv;` does not update the value.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You're creating a huge amount of variables which don't really do much, and is very hard to read. Also, you don't need to keep calling `ToArray` Try something like this:

```
for(int p = 0; p < myList.Count; ++p)
{
    decimal? fv = (myList[p].value * 10) / ((decimal?)a_constant);
    givenList[p].value = fv;
}
```

Comment: You might want to check `myList[p]` is `null` first before `.value`... Cause if it is `null` you will hit error

Comment: @Nic I agree, but without knowing the specific use of this method, it would be difficult to write an error-case which is objectively better than simply hitting the null reference exception :)

Comment: Well if i recall correctly you can remove `.Value` the code still will work and you won't be hitting null reference exception :)

Comment: @Nic Depends if it's a `Nullable<T>` or just an object with a `value` property (probably the latter since it's lower case)

Comment: Anywhere the answer is correct :). The rest is up to him we are just discussing better approach for error handling.

Answer (score 0):

`tl.ToArray()` creates a copy of each element. I'm not sure what is the type of `myElement` in the code, but if it's a `struct` or any other `value type` that would explain why your collection is not being modified. Your code would update a copy of your element, not the element itself